# Stop an embedded UITableView from being offset vertically

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, offset

I have a storyboard which has a `UINavigationController` with a root `UIViewController`.  That view controller has a `UIContainerView`, with an embedded `UITableView`.

`UINavigationController` >> `UIViewController` >> `UIContainerView` >> `UITableViewController`

When the screen opens, I see the `UIViewController` (with a navigation bar), and the embedded `UITableView` inside the `UIContainerView`.  However the embedded `UITableView` has been offset vertically down the page by 60px (i.e. the height of the statusbar and the navigationbar).

How do I tell the `UITableViewController` NOT to inherit the offset from the parent `UINavigationController` and `UIStatusBar`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the rootviewController in storyboard, select the 'attributes inspector' in the utilities pane, then find a checkbox marked Adjust Scroll View Insets and uncheck it